# get group of same elements

Tags: jquery, css

Is there an easy way to click on three button links to set an action, and leave the top  link (one) alone, without adding additional classes to this HTML markup?

```
<div id="mlinks">
  <a href="one">one</a>
  <a href="two">two</a>
  <a href="three">three</a>
  <a href="four">four</a>
</div>


//SET THIS ON CLICK EVENT TO COMMUNICATE WITH THE BOTTOM 3 LINKS, AND LEAVE THE FIRST ONE ALONE.
$('#mlink a').on('click', function() {

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `slice` and take out `one`,

```
$('#mlink a').slice(1).on('click', function() {

});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RGCKu/

Comment: @blackhawk `:first`, `:gt` pseudo selectors internally uses slice.

Comment: @blackhawk `.first`, `.gt` functions internally uses `slice`. At least until 1.8.3 http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.8.3&fn=eq. Their implementation changed.. not sure how it is done in their latest version.

Answer (score 5):

use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to filter it out

```
$('#mlink a').not(':first').on('click',function(){ .. });
```

or [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and `:first`

```
$('#mlink a:not(:first)').on('click',function(){ .. });
```

or [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector - select all greater than index 0

```
$('#mlink a:gt(0)').on('click',function(){ .. });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.first()` or `.eq(0)` to remove the first link item:

```
var links = $('#mlink a');
links.not(links.first()).on('click', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mlinks a:first').nextAll().on('click', function() { });
```

check link: http://jsfiddle.net/7zDpY/